# Component Symbol identification; Rectangle with large T-shape

Tags: components, schematics, identification

I've been searching for days and still have not come up with an answer.

What is this symbol?:

[image]

The component in question was found on this [mosfet amplifier](http://farhek.com/jd/41i0751h/amp-elektor/11570ud/) schematic from the 1980s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like *preset* potentiometer wired as rheostat.
[Here](http://www.resistorguide.com/rheostat/) you can find the following definitions:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Long story short:
It's a variable resistor. Mainly used as a preset resistor (e.g. to equalize an DC offset)

See [Rapidtables](https://www.rapidtables.com/electric/electrical_symbols.html) as an example and search for "Trimmer Resistor" after maybe 1/3 of the page.

Comment: Aw! Please can we have the long story?